# Magento - Use config value inside module config file

Tags: magento

Is it possible to use a config value inside another modules config file - in much the same way you can grab a config file using getStoreConfig().

If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

No. All the (static) config XML files are read from the filesystem before any config values are retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can get any value from any of your xml files (all of them - config.xml, admin.xml etc are merged into one) like this:

```
    $config = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/sales/order/statuses');
    Zend_Debug::dump($config);
```